# Printing long int value in C

Tags: c

I have two variables of `long int` type as shown below:

```
long int a=-2147483648, b=-2147483648;
a=a+b;

printf("%d",a);
```

I am getting zero. I tried changing the type to `long long int`, but I'm still not getting the correct answer.

Comment: `%d` expects an `int`...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You must use `%ld` to print a `long int`, and `%lld` to print a `long long int`.

Note that only `long long int` is guaranteed to be large enough to store the result of that calculation (or, indeed, the input values you're using).

You will also need to ensure that you use your compiler in a C99-compatible mode (for example, using the `-std=gnu99` option to gcc).  This is because the `long long int` type was not introduced until C99; and although many compilers implement `long long int` in C90 mode as an extension, the constant `2147483648` may have a type of `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` in C90.  If this is the case in your implementation, then the value of `-2147483648` will also have unsigned type and will therefore be positive, and the overall result will be not what you expect.

Comment: int main()
{
    long long int a,b;
    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
    a=a+b;
    printf("%lld",a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}        still no luck sir....

Comment: @JijoPi use `%lld` for `scanf()` too.

Comment: int main()
{
    long long int a,b;
    a=-2147483648;
    b=a;
    a=a+b;
    printf("%lld",a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}...............still not getting the answer...i thk the sign is lost..

Comment: @JijoPi - Just tried your program verbatim, and it worked. What is your wordsize? (what is the output of `printf("%d",sizeof(long long int));`?)

Comment: @cluracan: It is because the OP is using a C90 compiler that supports `long long int` as an extension, rather than a C99 compiler.  It is treating `2147483648` under C90 rules as a 32-bit `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, and the result of negating it is the same value.

Comment: @caf - tried compiling with c90, and got the same result: everything works. The result of negating an unsigned number isn't the same number, it's the negation as expected: "The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting the promoted value from the largest value of the promoted type and adding one" [ANSI C A.7.4.5]. In other words - it does what you think it does.

Comment: @caf - sorry, I now understand what you meant: 2147483648 specifically is the same as -2147483648 in 32 bit. But unless you add a `u` at the end of the number, it should be interpreted as `signed`, not `unsigned`. So it should (and does, in my case, using two different c90 compilers) work as expected

Comment: @cluracan: Exactly what type the constant has depends on the widths of your basic types.  If you have a C90 compiler with a 64 bit `long int`, then the type of `2147483648` will be of type `long int` (so, signed).  However, if your C90 compiler has a 32 bit `long int`, then the type of `2147483648` will be `unsigned long int`.  This is defined in §3.1.3.2 in the C90 standard: *The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.  Unsuffixed decimal: `int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`*.

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf("%ld",a);`

Have a look at [format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) for printf

Answer (score 3):

### To take input " *long int* " and output " *long int* " in C is :

```
long int n;
scanf("%ld", &n);
printf("%ld", n);
```

### To take input " *long long int* " and output " *long long int* "  in C is :

```
long long int n;
scanf("%lld", &n);
printf("%lld", n);
```

Hope you've cleared..